# Removing a line from a file which has only specific character

Tags: linux

How to remove a particular line which contains only end of line character in Unix.

The content of file is as follows,

```
H       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       ""$SEQ_NO $
$
D^I001000456108^IU$
```

It should be,

```
H       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       ""$SEQ_NO $
D^I001000456108^IU$
```

Comment: what you have tried till now?

Comment: sed '2d' filename

Comment: What do you mean with "end of line character"? Does your file contain actual dollar signs at the end of each line, or is the output from something like `cat -e` that marks the end-of-line so trailing whitespace is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
sed '/^\$*$/d' filename
```

**Sample**

```
$ cat filename
H       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       ""$SEQ_NO $
$
D^I001000456108^IU$

$ sed '/^\$*$/d' filename
H       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       ""$SEQ_NO $
D^I001000456108^IU$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed(1)` to delete all lines consisting of CRs only:

```
cat your_file.txt | sed -e '/^$/d'
```

Comment: this will only remove blank line

Comment: (It's LF, not CR, and you can just do `sed -e ... your_file.txt`, without the cat)  But this isn't wrong, the question is just a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -vx '\s*\$\s*' file.txt
```

- `-x` Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line
- `-v` Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines
- `\s*` zero or more white-space characters
- `\$` match `$` character

If it is known that leading and trailing white-spaces are not there in lines concerned:

```
grep -vx '\$' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just:

```
grep . < file.in > file.out
```

`grep .` looks for lines that contain at least one character. So that's all the lines except the empty ones or the ones that contain byte sequences that don't form any single valid character.

With:

```
LC_ALL=C grep .
```

We'd make sure every byte sequence forms valid characters, so it would keep those invalid text lines if any. Or you could use:

```
grep -vx ''
```

Another option is:

```
awk length < file.in > file.out
```

Again, you may find `awk` implementations where `length` may return 0 for lines that only contain non-characters.

If you want to remove lines that consist of only one `$` character (followed by the newline character), then:

```
grep -vxF '$' < file.in > file.out
```